# Incrementing value on backtrack

Tags: prolog, increment, backtracking, swi-prolog

how can I do increment on backtracking ... so that goal(S) receives incremented number .. every time it fails on the next run I want to get the next number

```
S1 is S + 1,goal(S1)
```

does not work, because :

```
?- S=0, S1 is S+1.
S = 0,
S1 = 1.

?- S=0,between(1,3,_), S1 is S+1.
S = 0,
S1 = 1 ;
S = 0,
S1 = 1 ;
S = 0,
S1 = 1.
```

---

this work

```
%%counting
baz(..,C) :- .... arg(...), Y is X + 1, nb_setarg(...), goal(Y), ...

foo(..C) :- ....baz(....,C)..., foo(...C).


%%counter
blah :- ....foo(....,counter(0))...
```

this is not working, i think cause the recursive foo() would force baz() to initialize counter(0)... but i'm good with @sligo solution above

```
baz(..) :- C = counter(0), ....  arg(...), Y is X + 1, nb_setarg(...), goal(Y), ...
foo(..) :- ....baz(....)..., foo(...).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *non-backtrackable destructive assignment* predicate [nb_setarg/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nb_setarg/3):

```
?- C = counter(0), between(1, 3, _), arg(1, C, X), Y is X + 1, nb_setarg(1, C, Y).
C = counter(1),
X = 0,
Y = 1 ;
C = counter(2),
X = 1,
Y = 2 ;
C = counter(3),
X = 2,
Y = 3.
```

Alternatives:

```
foo(C) :-
    between(1, inf, C), 
    goal(C),
    !.

baz(C) :-
    C = counter(0),
    repeat,
        arg(1, C, X),
        Y is X + 1,
        nb_setarg(1, C, Y),
        goal(Y),
        !.

goal(X) :-
    X > 9.
```

Examples:

```
?- foo(C).
C = 10.

?- baz(C).
C = counter(10).
```

Answer (score 3):

> so that goal(S) receives incremented number .. every time it fails on the next run I want to get the next number

That's what `between/3` does? Every time on backtracking it makes the next number:

```
goal(X) :- 
  write('inside goal, X is '), 
  write(X),
  nl.

test :-
  between(0, 3, S),
  goal(S).
```

e.g.

```
?- test.
inside goal, X is 0
true ;
inside goal, X is 1
true ;
inside goal, X is 2
true ;
inside goal, X is 3
true ;
```

Edit: From the [help for between/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3):

> between(+Low, +High, ?Value)
>
> Low and High are integers, High >=Low. If Value is an integer,
> Low =<Value =<High. When Value is a variable it is successively
> bound to all integers between Low and High. If High is `inf` or
> `infinite` between/3 is true iff Value >=Low, a feature that is
> particularly interesting for generating integers from a certain value.

(And see the comments on the help page by LogicalCaptain)

Comment: between requires to specify upper limit, but more importantly which i forgot to mention the counter has to be outside of the scope of the actual counting/incrementing ...which i saw after i tried to apply the @slago answer

Comment: @sten you can specify an upper limit of `between(0, inf, S)` for infinity. I don't understand what you mean by the counter being outside the scope of the counting?

Comment: will post example